# How to reuse a pre middleware function in mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I need to reuse one of pre middleware functions in another pre middleware, for that I extracted a function like so:

```
async function encryptPassword(next) {
    if (!this.isModified('password')) {
        return next();
    }
    this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 5);
    this.passwordChangedAt = new Date();
    next();
}

UserSchema.pre('save', encryptPassword);

UserSchema.pre("findOneAndUpdate", encryptPassword);
```

But I am getting an error saying that `this.isModified` is not a function, I assume that `this` is referring to something else. How to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I dived into these pre/post hooks with a help of debugger & docs and I have found several things (these apply to both `pre` and `post`):

Using `save` hook will mean that `this` refers a document itself. Thus, you can update its fields, call methods like `isModified`, etc. You should not have any issues with the above method.

However, `findOneAndUpdate` hook will mean that `this` refers to a **query** instead of document. And Query object will not have documents or their inherited methods (like `isModified`).

I checked with debugger and can confirm it is the case (up-to-date with documentation).

A list of hooks: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#types-of-middleware

You will see that only the following hooks allow to modify documents:

```
validate
save
remove
updateOne
deleteOne
init (note: init hooks are synchronous)
```

And all others will not. It seems this is intentional (https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/964).

To solve an issue with `findOneAndUpdate`, it seems the only way (most closely resembling) is to rework to `findOne` and `updateOne` as separate queries.